# Как лучше найти вхождение подстроки в большом тексте?

Tags: алгоритм, java

Как лучше реализовать считывание из файла большого текста и нахождение в нём вхождений подстроки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Префикс функция и КМП e-maxx.ru](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/prefix_function)

[Префикс функция вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[Алгоритм КМП вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0)

Можно так, например. Почитайте, если что непонятно, попытаюсь пояснить на примере.

**Обновление**

Можно в `String`, способов считывания множество есть в общем-то, можно в байтовый массив. Как пример, если поиск подстроки будет с помощью КМП, то можно сперва подстроку записать в `StringBuilder`, затем `BufferedReader`'ом добавить содержимое файла и работать уже дальше по алгоритму со строкой полученной.

Comment: Все к этому алгоритму и шло =) а куда тогда из файла считать текст, в одну переменную string норм будет?

Comment: Обновил ответ